# Why does this ID-selection not work in Jsoup?

Tags: java, select, jsoup

I am trying to get data from a webpage (http://steamcommunity.com/id/Winning117/games/?tab=all) using a specific tag but I keep getting null. My desired result is to get the "hours played" for a specific game - Cluckles' Adventure in this case.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class TestScrape {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Winning117/games/?tab=all";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        
        Element playTime = document.select("div#game_605250").first();
        System.out.println(playTime);
    }
}
```

Edit: How can I tell if a webpage is using JavaScript and is therefore unable to be parsed by Jsoup?

Comment: try this : playTime.select(".ellipsis hours_played")

Comment: @thanga Which part are you suggesting I replace with that line of code? Sorry I just yesterday started using Jsoup so I'm not familiar with it

Comment: The data you're looking for is being loaded dynamically with some JavaScript code so you cannot scrape it with Jsoup. You need to use headless browser, like PhantomJS.

Comment: @TDG How can you tell if something is being loaded with JavaScript? I was able to pull from a Steam leaderboard page without trouble but I assume that means it didn't use JavaScript

Comment: You can disable JavaScript at your browser (there are plugins for that) and then load the page. If you don't see the data you're looking for - it's Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute javascript in java code there is Selenium :

> Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each
>   browser’s native support for automation.

To include it with maven use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Next I give you code of simple JUnit test that creates instance of WebDriver and goes to given url and executes simple script to get `rgGames` .
File `chromedriver` you have to download at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.

```
package SeleniumProject.selenium;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ChromeTest extends TestCase {

    private static ChromeDriverService service;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createAndStartService() {
        service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"))
                .withVerbose(false).usingAnyFreePort().build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("service didn't start");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void createAndStopService() {
        service.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void createDriver() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testJS() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        // Load a new web page in the current browser window.
        driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/id/Winning117/games/?tab=all");

        // Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or
        // window.
        ArrayList<Map> list = (ArrayList<Map>) js.executeScript("return rgGames;");
        // Map represent properties for one game
        for (Map map : list) {
            for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                // take each key to find key "name" and compare its vale to
                // Cluckles' Adventure
                if (key instanceof String && key.equals("name") && map.get(key).equals("Cluckles' Adventure")) {
                    // print all properties for game Cluckles' Adventure
                    map.forEach((key1, value) -> {
                        System.out.println(key1 + " : " + value);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see selenium loads page at

```
driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/id/Winning117/games/?tab=all");
```

And to get data of all games by Winning117 it returns `rgGames` variable:

```
ArrayList<Map> list = (ArrayList<Map>) js.executeScript("return rgGames;");
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you want to scrape is load by js,and there is not any #game_605250 element that jsoup get.All datas are write in page by using js.

But when I print document to a file  ,I see some data like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
        var rgGames = [{"appid":224260,"name":"No More Room in Hell","logo":"http:\/\/cdn.steamstatic.com.8686c.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/224260\/670e9aba35dc53a6eb2bc686d302d357a4939489.jpg","friendlyURL":224260,"availStatLinks":{"achievements":true,"global_achievements":true,"stats":false,"leaderboards":false,"global_leaderboards":false},"hours_forever":"515","last_played":1492042097},{"appid":241540,"name":"State of Decay","logo":"http:\/\/....
```

then,you can extract 'rgGames' by some StringTools and format it to json obj.

It't not a clerver method,but it worked

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class TestScrape {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Winning117/games/?tab=all";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Element playTime = document.select("div#game_605250");
        Elements val = playTime.select(".hours_played");
        System.out.println(val.text());

    }
}
```

Comment: It throws `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TestScrape.main(TestScrape.java:12)` with line 12 being "Elements val = " etc

Comment: modified the answer.Please check now. It should text()

Comment: i dont have environment to test this. changed the class name. check now

Comment: Tried it again with `.hours_played` and it still throws the same exception :(

Comment: is playTime null ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143149/discussion-between-thanga-and-josh-correia).